# Removing an item from a multidimensional array in php by value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array `$array` that looks like this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[500]
          public 'id' => int 2
          public 'first_name' => string 'Mary' (length=4)
          public 'last_name' => string 'Sweet' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[501]
          public 'id' => int 9
          public 'first_name' => string 'Joe' (length=3)
          public 'last_name' => string 'Bob' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[502]
          public 'id' => int 1
          public 'first_name' => string 'Shag' (length=4)
          public 'last_name' => string 'Well' (length=4)
```

I would like to be able to remove one of the items in the array by searching for values **(not indexes)**.

So, I would like to remove the item in the array that has the **first_name** property of **'Joe'**.

So if I removed it, the array would look like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[500]
          public 'id' => int 2
          public 'first_name' => string 'Mary' (length=4)
          public 'last_name' => string 'Sweet' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[502]
          public 'id' => int 1
          public 'first_name' => string 'Shag' (length=4)
          public 'last_name' => string 'Well' (length=4)
```

How would I be able to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could just use a foreach in this case. It will work just fine. Just use your search string needle and add an if inside the loop comparing the objects property firstname and the needle:

```
$first_name_search = 'Joe';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $value = reset($value); // get that index 0 which is nested 
    if($value->first_name == $first_name_search) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```